# Creating a QApplication inside of a method in non-qt application

Tags: qt, qtgui

I have a larger application and I want to create GUI dialog for one specific subtask. I decided to use Qt but I am not familiar with it so I am doing this thing probably the wrong way.

My quick and dirty prototype:

```
void ManualFeatureMatcher::matchFeatures() {
    int argc = 0;
    char* argv[1] = {NULL};
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    a.exec();
}
```

This works fine the first time the function is called but when I call it again I get these errors:

```
    (app:8540): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

    (app:8540): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

    (app:8540): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

    (app:8540): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
```

What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You don't need another QApplication instance, just create your dialog and show it. Modal dialogs contain its own event loop inside.

Comment: Nesting multiple QApplications are not supported - I also can't think of a reason why you should need that.

Comment: I don't have any other QApplication instance at the time this method is called. At the moment nothing else except this method in my application knows anything about qt.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then your question title is misleading though.

Comment: QApplication instance is usually created in your main() function. Or are you trying to spawn Qt in a non-Qt application?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I have made smart pointer to QApplication a member of the class and made sure it is created only once.

Instead of pure Widgets i use QDialogs now so I do not need to run the QApplication loop because as @Archie said in the comment: Modal dialogs contain its own loop inside.

More details on [blog](http://blog.honzabrabec.cz/2013/10/20/how-to-use-qt-only-in-part-of-your-application/)